# Fetching and Formatting Nested JSON Data from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to fetch data from an SQL Server database and format it into a nested JSON structure using C#. I have a table named 'tbl_student' with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_student 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Age INT,
    City NVARCHAR(255),
    Tags NVARCHAR(500),
    S_tag Nvarchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_student (ID, Name, Age, City, Tags,S_tag)
VALUES
    (1, 'John Doe', 30, 'New York', 'tag1,tag2,tag3','tag5'),
    (2, 'Jane Smith', 25, 'Los Angeles', 'tag4,tag5','tag3'),
    (3, 'Bob Johnson', 40, 'Chicago', 'tag2,tag3','tag1'),
    (4, 'Alice Brown', 28, 'San Francisco', 'tag5,tag1','tag2'),
    (5, 'Charlie White', 35, 'Seattle', 'tag1,tag3,tag2','tag4');
```

In the database:

[image]

I am attempting to retrieve records in the following JSON format in C# for Id is 1:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Age": 30,
    "City": "New York",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Name": "Jane Smith",
        "Age": 25,
        "City": "Los Angeles"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bob Johnson",
        "Age": 40,
        "City": "Chicago"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Alice Brown",
        "Age": 28,
        "City": "San Francisco"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to prepare tags array for each row based on `S_Tags` column

What I tried:

```
SELECT
    main.Name AS Name,
    main.Age AS Age,
    main.City AS City,
    (SELECT
         sub.Name AS Name,
         sub.Age AS Age,
         sub.City AS City
     FROM
         tbl_student AS sub
     WHERE
         CHARINDEX(sub.Tags, main.Tags) > 0
     FOR JSON PATH) AS Tags
FROM
    tbl_student AS main
```

but I'm not getting the expected output:

[image]

Kindly help me rectify what I am doing wrong here/any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to break out the `Tags` column inside a subquery, then re-join that back to the table.

```sql
SELECT
  s.Name,
  s.Age,
  s.City,
  (
    SELECT
      other.Name,
      other.Age,
      other.City
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.Tags, ',') t
    JOIN tbl_student other ON other.S_tag = t.value
    WHERE other.ID <> s.ID
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS Tags
FROM tbl_student s
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/76KzjbZ6)

I hope I don't need to tell you that this data is denormalized, the `Tags` column should really be a separate table.

Also, storing `Age` in a database is rather silly, it would keep changing. Better to store the DOB and calculate the age from that.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is including "student tags" where the student's tag list is a substring of the student's.  Instead, you want to use `sub.S_tag`.

```
       SELECT
             main.Name AS Name,
             main.Age AS Age,
             main.City AS City,
             (
                 SELECT
                     sub.Name AS Name,
                     sub.Age AS Age,
                     sub.City AS City
                 FROM
                     tbl_student AS sub
                 WHERE
                     -- only include sub's where sub.S_tag exists in main.Tags
                     -- note we check for "," to avoid "tag1" matching "tag11, tag12, etc."
                     CHARINDEX(sub.S_tag+ ",", main.Tags) > 0 or
                     CHARINDEX("," + sub.S_tag, main.Tags) > 0                            
                 FOR JSON PATH
             ) AS Tags
         FROM
             tbl_student AS main
```

Sidenote, this is a strange way to build a 1 to many relationship (Student --> Tags) in a relational database.  Another approach is to have a table like `StudentTags` that you can query using a join to build the 1:n relationship.

Comment: Small note, sub.TagId should be sub.S_Tag based on the given structure.